# Why did I get "Internal polygon error 71" in eagle?

Tags: eaglecad, error

I attempted to create a ground plane for my circuit with the polygon command but this time, I get a weird problem. Normally when I create a rectangle and rename the polygon to GND (ground), I'm asked what the new name of the track should be and then the blank spots of the circuit board are filled in mostly with GND which is normal.

However, this time, I did the same thing to a bit more complex of a circuit, and just after drawing the polygon and associating it with GND, I get the following error:

```
Error:

ABORT: Internal Polygon Error 71
```

It gives me an OK and cancel button to click on. Once I click on either button, the entire program immediately exits.

What could cause this? and I'm using Eagle 4.16r2.

Comment: Picture please. Are any parts of the polygon overlapping?

Comment: Nobody is going to give a crap what problems you encounter in version 4 of Eagle.  The current version is 7.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Eagle 7.7) this error was associated with elements on the "Dimension" layer. This layer defines the outermost boundaries for all polygons. Please try the following:

- Display dimension layer only
- Remove all elements except for the PCB contour

Edit: If this does not help, try to increase the width of the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/14137/l/abort-internal-polygon-error-71?displayFullThread=true). BTW, version of EAGLE you use relatively old one, I do not think you will be able to get proper vendor support for it...

Try creating smaller polygon, check its properties (share screenshot of properties with us) and then extend it (move its points) to the area of your desire.